# Search for a file by the date of it

Tags: bash, shell, date, if-statement

I'm doing a Script which should search in a path for a File by its Date. I tried it with the name itself because in there is a Date too. (For Example: stargate_speedtests_2015-10-07-09:03:01) And after I get the File i want to Zip it.

```
datetoday="date '+%Y-%m-%d'"
LOCATION="/data/outgoing/cnlab/"
FILENAME="$LOCATION/stargate_speedtests_$datetoday"


if ((-f ${FILENAME[@]} ))
    then        
        tar -czf $FILENAME.tar.gz $FILENAME.csv

        find . -name '$FILENAME' -maxdepth 1 -print0 | 
        tar -czf "$FILENAME".tar.gz --null -T -
        ZIP="$FILENAME.tar.gz"
else 
        echo "$FILENAME not found"
fi
```

Comment: Y-m-d H:i:s is not a **timestamp**, it's a **date**. a timestamp is like 1444224341. By the way if the file is on this form for 100% sure, then you should `find . -name "stargate_speedtests_*" -maxdepth 1 -print0`. Btw again, your question is not clear to me.

Comment: Oh sorry about this fail. I changed it, yeah i know i could find it by this way but the problem is there are more than just one file. Every day there will be one generated and when I use this script i want the file from Today and not from 2015-10-06

Comment: Ok then you should be able to find the file of today (-24 hours) with `find . -name "stargate_speedtests_$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')*` or maybe for a file created today (since midnight) : `touch -t $(date +%m%d0000) /tmp/$$; find . -newer /tmp/$$; rm tmp/$$`

Comment: mh thank you for the input but i'm a newbie how does find work with a if loop?

Comment: how does what work ? **if** is a condition, not a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try the operand -newerat.

```
datetoday="$(date +%Y-%m-%d)"

find . -type f -newerat "$datetoday"
```

Not this is not a POSIX supported operand for `date`.

Comment: `-newerXY` is a not available in all versions of `find` (not specified by POSIX). Now, `-newerat` will check for access time, not modification time (use `-newermt` instead). Moreover, it will find files that are _newer_ than the specified date (not _made at a specific date_).

Answer (score 0):

If you assume the files all have names that are formatted:

/path/to/file/random_filename_TIME_NOW

Where TIME_NOW is of the format 2015-10-07-09:03:01

Then it sounds like this will solve your problem:

```
for k in *; do echo "$k" | grep `date +%Y-%m-%d`; done
```

If on the other hand you want to find the time from the system timestamps then remember that there are actually three kinds of timestamps:

Access -- The last time that the file was accessed

Modify -- The last time that the content of the file was modified

Change -- The last time that the file metadata, (e.g. permissions) was changed

Actually there is a fourth but is isn't in POSIX so it won't always work:

Birth -- The time that the file was created

The commands for these are as follows when looking in the current directory (using stat):

Access

```
for k in *;do STATS=`stat -c %x "$k"`; echo "${STATS} $k"; done | grep "^`date +%Y-%m-%d`" | sed 's/\S\{1,\} \S\{1,\} \S\{1,\} //'
```

Modify

```
for k in *;do STATS=`stat -c %y "$k"`; echo "${STATS} $k"; done | grep "^`date +%Y-%m-%d`" | sed 's/\S\{1,\} \S\{1,\} \S\{1,\} //'
```

Change

```
for k in *;do STATS=`stat -c %z "$k"`; echo "${STATS} $k"; done | grep "^`date +%Y-%m-%d`" | sed 's/\S\{1,\} \S\{1,\} \S\{1,\} //'
```

Birth

```
for k in *;do STATS=`stat -c %w "$k"`; echo "${STATS} $k"; done | grep "^`date +%Y-%m-%d`" | sed 's/\S\{1,\} \S\{1,\} \S\{1,\} //'
```